# create a new column that contains a list of values from another column subsequent rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like below,

[image: current table]

and want to create a new column that contains a list of values from another column subsequent rows like below,

[image: New Table]

for copy paste:
timestamp       ID      Value

2021-12-03 04:03:45     ID1         O

2021-12-03 04:03:46     ID1         P

2021-12-03 04:03:47     ID1         Q

2021-12-03 04:03:48     ID1         R

2021-12-03 04:03:49     ID1         NULL

2021-12-03 04:03:50     ID1         S

2021-12-03 04:03:51     ID1         T

2021-12-04 11:09:03     ID2         A

2021-12-04 11:09:04     ID2         B

2021-12-04 11:09:05     ID2         C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are complex and it wasn't easy to code this — but a triple join, rules for nulls, and removing the first element can produce the results as desired:

```sql
with data as (
select (x[0]||' '||x[1])::timestamp ts, x[2]::string id, iff(x[3]='NULL', null, x[3])::string value
from (
select split(value, ' ') x
from table(split_to_table($$2021-12-03 04:03:45 ID1 O
2021-12-03 04:03:46 ID1 P
2021-12-03 04:03:47 ID1 Q
2021-12-03 04:03:48 ID1 R
2021-12-03 04:03:49 ID1 NULL
2021-12-03 04:03:50 ID1 S
2021-12-03 04:03:51 ID1 T
2021-12-04 11:09:03 ID2 A
2021-12-04 11:09:04 ID2 B
2021-12-04 11:09:05 ID2 C$$, '\n')) 
))


select ts, id, value, iff( -- return null for null values
    value is null
    , null
    , array_to_string(
        array_slice( -- remove first element
            array_agg(bvalue) within group (order by bts)
            , 1, 99999)
        , ',')
) list
from (
    select a.*, b.ts bts, b.value bvalue
        , coalesce( -- find max null after current value, or max value if none
        (
            select max(ts)
            from data
            where a.id=id
            and value is null
            and a.ts<ts
        ),
        (
            select max(ts)
            from data
            where a.id=id
        )) maxts
    from data a
    join data b
    on a.id=b.id
    and a.ts<=b.ts
    where maxts >= b.ts
)
group by id, ts, value
order by id, ts
```

[image]

Comment: If I understood the question correctly the rule is actually pretty simple. The desired resultset it to build cummulative string aggregation skiping actual row up to first NULL or end of the window. Unfortunatelly I woudn't find a cummulative array_agg/listagg function available. If that would be the case then it could be as simple as `LISTAGG(COALESCE(value, '<sep>'), ',') OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY timestamp)` and then substring (removing first entry) up to first <sep>

Answer (score 2):

Using windowed functions and range JOIN:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT tab.*, 
     COALESCE(FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN VALUE IS NULL THEN tmp END) IGNORE NULLS 
                OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMP 
                ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
             ,MAX(tmp) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)) AS next_tmp
  FROM tab
)
SELECT c1.tmp, c1.id, c1.value,
      LISTAGG(c2.value, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY c2.tmp) AS list
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.ID = c2.ID
 AND (c1.tmp < c2.tmp AND c2.tmp <= c1.next_tmp)
GROUP BY c1.tmp, c1.id, c1.value
ORDER BY c1.ID, c1.tmp;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d995b56b44954f928d5e20bef1df87ab)**

Output:

[image]

---

**How does it work:**

The idea is to find first timestamp corresponding to NULL value per each ID:

```
SELECT tab.*, 
 COALESCE(FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN VALUE IS NULL THEN tmp END) IGNORE NULLS 
            OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMP 
            ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
         , MAX(tmp) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)) AS next_tmp
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data that is ordered by `TMP` is also ordered by `ID` logically.

So, you can

1. group rows first by ID;
2. in each group, create a new group when the previous VALUE is null;
3. in each subgroup, use the comma to join up VALUEs from the second to the last non-null VALUE to form a sequence and make it the value of the new column LIST.

A SQL set is unordered, which makes computing process very complicated.

You need to first create a marker column using the window function, perform a self-join by the marker column, and group rows and join up VALUE values to get the desired result.

A common alternative is to fetch the original data out of the database and process it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easy to be integrated into a Java program and generates much simpler code. It can get it done with only two lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =ORACLE.query("SELECT * FROM TAB ORDER BY 1") |
| 2 | =A1.group@o(#2).conj(~.group@i(#3[-1]==null).run(tmp=~.(#3).select(~),~=~.derive(tmp.m(#+1:).concat@c():LIST))).conj() |